# How to uncompress perforce Depot files

Tags: perforce

**- how to uncompress perforce Depot files?**

The files I have now ending with [**,v**] and some files end with [**,d**] containing [**1.1.gz**].

What i did In details:

In **P4V** I created a **Workspace**, put some important files, **Submit**ted it to the **Depot** then decided to delete what's in the **Depot** by clicking **Mark for Delete** it just mark it with a red X what I think, So I head to C:\Program Files\Perforce\Server\depot and deleting it from there, now the files in the **Recycle Bin** but doing so doesn't make it disappear from **P4V** so I opened **P4Abmin** in the Depot tap I did **Obliterate** and its gone finally.

Later discovered that **Marking files for Delete** in the **Depot** delets it from the **Workspace**, and only thing that I have is what I restored from the **Recycle Bin** and it's compressed files, how can I uncompress it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't touch the Perforce server's depot or db files unless you know what you're doing -- normally the server handles the job of managing those files and the relationships between them, and randomly messing with those files will usually break things, much like if you randomly shuffled blocks on your hard disk around without knowing how your filesystem works.  I mention this first so that you'll know for next time, and second so that if you happen to have access to a time machine, you can fix this problem by going back and informing your past self to keep their paws out of P4ROOT.  :)
2. If in the future you want to temporarily delete files from the depot, use the normal "Mark for Delete" command in P4V (or `p4 delete` in the CLI) followed by "Submit".  If you want to permanently delete them, that's what the "obliterate" command is for.  In neither case should you be deleting files out from under the server -- everything should happen from the client (that is, P4V, the p4 CLI, P4Win, etc).
3. If you restore the deleted files to exactly where they were, you should be able to rely on Perforce to get the files back, provided you have not already obliterated them from the db.  (Hopefully obliterate noticed the archive files were gone and it failed with an error instead of blasting the db entries...)
4. If you no longer have the db entries for the files, you can try to extract the archives manually with command line tools (luckily the content isn't encrypted or in a weird proprietary format) -- you should be able to `gunzip` the `.gz` files and `co` (RCS) the `,v` files.  I'd expect most unzip utilities to understand gzip, but RCS is a pretty old format so you may have to do a little digging to find Windows tools for it (I think Cygwin may have RCS tools bundled with it).  Good luck!

Comment: I Just extracted the archives manually and everything is working. Thanks